# How to properly use multiple controllers in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I am trying to use 2 controllers with one dispatcher servlet in Spring MVC. But I am running into 404 errors when trying to render the views. The dispatcher is pretty straightforward, from web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    ...
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.azalea" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

The controllers are:

```
package com.mycompany.azalea;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public class homeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
         return "index";
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.mycompany.azalea;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/data")
public class dataController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
         return "index";
    }
}
```

and I am using a pretty standard resolver:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

// Resolve logical view names to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory
@Bean
ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Views are set up under WEB-INF/views/home/ and WEB-INF/views/data/

However if I try to request a URL like `http://localhost:8080/Azalea/home/`

I get an entry in the GlassFish log:

SEVERE: PWC6117: File ".../build/web/**home**/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp" not found

instead of the expected request for

".../build/web/WEB-INF/views/**home**/index.jsp"

Same pattern for "/data". It essentially looks like the request mapping is inserted into the wrong position in the request.

My current work around is to modify the resolver to

```
resolver.setPrefix("../WEB-INF/views/");
```

and return the following from the controller:

public class homeController {

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
         return "home/index";
    }
}
```

But this seems to be a suboptimal solution. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. The prefix has to be absolute here to make it work the way you want it to. That is: The `prefix` for the view-resolver has to be set as an absolute:

```
resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
```

And, when you return the view names from the `@RequestMapping` methods, they have to be the paths relative to your `view-resolver`'s `prefix` path. So, in the `homeController`, you should return `home/index`, and in your `dataController`, you should return `data/index`.